# What are Mongoose ODM's ObjectId?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Looking at the [Mongoose ODM docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html), it doesn't really say much about what are `ObjectId's` and how they can be used. I think its something like foreign keys in MongoDB?

If so, Embedded Documents seem to achieve the same purpose, when do I use which?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It would be very worthwhile to read the MongoDB documentation or a quick MongoDB intro such as [The Little MongoDB Book](http://openmymind.net/2011/3/28/The-Little-MongoDB-Book/) (it's free) for some background on MongoDB concepts.

To answer your question:

- An [ObjectID](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Object+IDs) is a unique 12-byte identifier which can be generated by MongoDB as the primary key (`_id`) for a collection.  There is a [specification for the ObjectID](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Object+IDs#ObjectIDs-BSONObjectIDSpecification).
- A [DBRef (database reference)](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/database-references/) is an ObjectID referencing an object in another collection.  A DBRef does require require another query to fetch the related object, and is a convention supported by the client drivers rather than MongoDB server.  The Mongoid equivalent is called [referenced relations](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/relations.html).
- [Embedded documents](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Schema+Design#SchemaDesign-EmbeddingandLinking) are nested arrays or subdocuments within a document. In Mongoid these are [embedded relations](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/relations.html).

The approach to [data modelling and schema design](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Schema+Design) in MongoDB is very different from relational databases.  There are (intentionally) no joins or foreign keys, but the document-oriented approach allows large amounts of related data to be stored and fetched in a single document.  Depending on how you plan to query and update your data, embedding or linking may be a more suitable choice.  The [schema design](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Schema+Design) page on the MongoDB wiki has some helpful tips to get you started.